# Estimated Earnings from D/E Ratio, Accounts Receivable, and ROE

Tags: finance

DW Industries has a D/E ratio of 0.5 and an ROE of 0.1. For every dollar it has in its assets, DW produces \$0.2 in sales. In 2019, DW made all of its sales on credit with an average of \$2 million in Accounts Receivables. It took DW 30 days to collect the cash on purchases the clients made. What is your best estimate of the DW's 2020 Earnings ?

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards from the Days Outstanding (I'll leave the numbers out so as to not give away the complete answer since this seems like a homework problem):

If it took 30 days on average to collect receivables, and their average A/R balance was $AR$, then their sales $S$ were $S = AR * (365/30)$.

Now to get to assets, since they have \$0.2 in sales for every \$1 in Assets, their assets would be $A = S/0.2$.

Since equity is Assets minus debt,

$$
\begin{align}
     D/E &= \frac{(E-A)}{E} \\ &= 1 - \frac{A}{E}\\
     \implies \frac{A}{E} &= (1 - D/E)\\
     \implies E &= \frac{A}{(1-D/E)}\\
\end{align}
$$

So if their D/E ratio is 0.5, then $E=A/(1-0.5) = A/0.5 = 2*A$

If their ROE is 10% (0.1), then their earnings would be $0.1 * E$.